# Defining differentiability on a topological manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I am currently watching a series of lectures which are a part of International Winter School on Gravity and Light 2015 (by Prof. Frederick P. Schuller). In one of the lectures on differentiable manifolds he asks- Is the structure of a topological manifold enought to talk about differentiability of curves on the manifold?Can you construct from it a notion of differentiability? And he answers in the negative saying that the structure of a topological manifold is not good enough to define a notion of differentiability.

Why is this true? What is missing in the structure of a topological manifold that is preventing us from defining differentiability on it?

[Here is the video lecture link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSyTEwS4g80&index=4&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_)  Go to 01:43

Comment: According to a theorem of Dennis Sullivan (ca 1979), every topological manifold of dimension $\ne 4$ admits a unique Lipschitz structure. The latter allows you to do quite a bit of differential topology in the setting of topological manifolds, as long as you are comfortable with Sobolev spaces, etc. The key is the basic fact (Rademacher-Stepanov theorem) that Lipschitz functions are a.e. differentiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you could define a canonical differential structure in terms of topological data, then it would be homeomorphism-invariant, since homeomorphisms preserve topology. Once we have a differential structure, we know that locally we can talk about differentiability in terms of coordinates. The fact that there are local homeomorphisms of $\mathbb R^n$ that are not differentiable then leads to a contradiction.

For a concrete example, consider the topological manifold $M = \mathbb R$, the homeomorphism $\phi(x) = x + |x|/2$ thereof and the function $f : M \to \mathbb R : x \mapsto x$. This function $f$ is differentiable, but $f \circ \phi$ is not; so our differential structure is not homeomorphism-invariant. This example is pretty much universal: you can always find a homeomorphism that has the form $\psi(x,y,z,\ldots) = (\phi(x),y,z,\ldots)$ in some local coordinates.

Comment: I think it's more than that. Here, your two differentiable structure are not equal, but they're still difeomorphic. But there are some (topological) manifolds on which there exist multiple differential structures that are not even diffeomorphic to each other; e.g. there are 28 such different structures on the 7-sphere $S^7$.

Comment: @Najib: Exotic differential structures are definitely interesting, but I think that's the answer to a different question. Even in $\le 3$ dimensions where all smooth structures are equivalent, you can't say whether a curve/function is differentiable based only on topology.